# How to redirect web page if 404 error is recieved from clicking link?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, hyperlink

I have a link in a basic HTML page:

```
  <a href="http://Overview.html" style="text-decoration:none;"  Title="Reports">
  <h5>Overview</h5><br>
  </a>
```

The link is actually a blank HTML with a Tableau Viz embedded. When someone has permissions in Tableau it lets them view the page.  Otherwise they get an error page "Resource not found Please check the URL and try again."

The error page is a 404 and if this was asp.net I'd know how to handle this.  What I need to do is check for the 404 and if exists then redirect to another page (one that actually tells the user they do not have access and to email me to request access).

I'm a newb to JavaScript but I think that is going to be the solution... Could someone show me how to apply JavaScript to redirect to something like "http://denied.html" when 404 exists (what I will make my page)?  I have found some examples but am not sure where the script would go inside of my HTML?  Inside the link? at top of page (to check the links right away instead of waiting on the link to be clicked)?

Comment: use the onclick handler, do an ajax request to "pre-test" access and if you get 404, then send them to another page, otherwise let the submit complete unimpeded.  You should really be doing this server side though IMO.

Comment: Sounds great! Could you possibly provide a small example?  I'm a newb and while I know other languages, I may need walked thru this one.

Comment: _"When someone has permissions in Tableau it lets them view the page."_ How are permission in "Tableau" determined?

Comment: If you are using Tableau, why don't you use the Tableau APIs. Then you could probably check before you send them there to handle the issue on the page with the iframe itself. I've used them before and while I didn't to that specifically, I know the API can do pretty advanced stuff to interact with the visualization so I'd be shocked if it couldn't also just see if they have access.

Comment: I just got off the phone with Tableau (created a case with them).   They may come back with an API solution, but didn't suggest it off the top.

Comment: Permissions in Tableau are determined via the Tableau Server.  I'm not the Admin but almost 100% sure it is using windows auth

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this would be to add JavaScript (adding an event listener to the link) which:

1. Cancels the default behaviour of the link
2. Uses XMLHttpRequest or Fetch to request the URL
3. Tests the Status to see if it is a 200 OK response and then either:

   - Sets `location` to `the_link.href` *or*
   - Sets `location` to the other URL

The [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) will prevent this from working across origins (unless you can get the target origin to support CORS and give you permission).

Comment: This is exactly what I need.  Would it be too much to ask to provide an example?  when it's a success it is a 200 OK.